# Wireless adapter not indentifiable

Tags: wireless-networking, nvidia-geforce

I have a new lenovo ideapad 310, using windows 7 pro 64 bit
tried to install the wireless adapter and the nvidia card and both are not seen! the install process fails because they are not identifiable
what can i do??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure "new laptop" and "Windows 7" can really fit in the same sentence in 2017..

Anyway, Nvidia driver should be [this](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/113446), while Atheros's is [here](http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=fileinfo&id=2288&lang=en).